# Starting a 10.3.3 Weblogic domain raises NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

Right now I'm facing some kind of strange problem with a Weblogic domain. When it starts, raises the following error right after starting it up. Guess it is related to classes conflict but... does anyone know which jar is responsible or how to evade this situation? I' ve been looking inside the weblogic 10.3.3 jars with no findings...

PS. Could this be related to a update from a previous version which had the EnumerationIterator implemented?

```
<Jun 9, 2011 2:51:40 PM COT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server su
bsystem failed. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/utils/collectio
ns/EnumerationIterator
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/utils/collections/EnumerationIterator
        at weblogic.management.SpecialPropertiesHelper.configureFromSystemProper
ties(SpecialPropertiesHelper.java:559)
        at weblogic.management.SpecialPropertiesHelper.configureFromSystemProper
ties(SpecialPropertiesHelper.java:542)
        at weblogic.management.SpecialPropertiesProcessor.updateConfiguration(Sp
ecialPropertiesProcessor.java:37)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.initialize(Ru
ntimeAccessImpl.java:418)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start(Runt
imeAccessService.java:49)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesMan
ager.java:461)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServ
icesManager.java:166)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:802)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:489)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:446)
        at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:67)

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.utils.collections.Enumerat
ionIterator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.management.SpecialPropertiesHelper.configureFromSystemProper
ties(SpecialPropertiesHelper.java:559)
        at weblogic.management.SpecialPropertiesHelper.configureFromSystemProper
ties(SpecialPropertiesHelper.java:542)
        at weblogic.management.SpecialPropertiesProcessor.updateConfiguration(Sp
ecialPropertiesProcessor.java:37)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.initialize(Ru
ntimeAccessImpl.java:418)
        at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start(Runt
imeAccessService.java:49)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesMan
ager.java:461)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServ
icesManager.java:166)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:802)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:489)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:446)
        at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:67)
<Jun 9, 2011 2:51:40 PM COT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server stat
e changed to FAILED>
```

Thanks in advance.

PS. For the record, it is installed in a WinServer 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find `weblogic/utils/collections/EnumerationIterator` within my running domain or console app on 10.3.3.

But it does appear within 2 jar files in the Oracle/Middleware HOME directory, i.e. witin the Weblogic installation folders.

```
D:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\com.bea.core.utils.full_1.8.0.0.jar
D:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\wlthint3client.jar
```

The first seems to be a common module used by all Middleware products including WL Server.
And the second from the name `wlthint3client` might be what you're looking for - it's within the WL Server lib and your stacktrace refers to the internal t3 service

Comment: I'll check if the thint3client does the trick (the server is not at reach and i'm gonna check it by myself just today...)

Comment: The thing was not finding this library because the path to its folder was not available in the PATH. Hence, here is your accepted response. Thanks.

Comment: @Alfabravo: WLHOME/server/lib is in the start classpath for Weblogic - I thought you would not have to specify it separately, anyways glad it helped.